# Numbered Section not appearing in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I'm working on my thesis. I've followed the same pattern to generate sections and subsections in each chapter. Everything is fine except that out of two section of the last chapter, only one is appearing in TOC.The second one doesn't appear in TOC. I'm using report class.

```
\chapter{ABC}

\section{D}

abcd

\section{E}
```

I'm unable to understand why is it a problem in last chapter and not anywhere else.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}


\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[left=32mm,right=20mm,top=28mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{stackengine}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
\setstretch{1.5}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
%If you want dots even for chapters and parts
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for parts
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal code illustrating the problem?

Comment: Did you compile twice without error? Since it only affects the last chapter, we're not likely to be able to tell much from your preamble. Did you use `\appendix` or `\backmatter`? Off-topic: you're loading `hyperref` too early.